# How to use manifest with abstract type

Tags: scala, manifest

I hava a compilation error while using manifest with abstract type :

```
[error] No Manifest available for C#MV#A.
[error]     def readGenSingle4[C <: MultiItemValue](h: Seq[C#MV] => C, json: JValue, g:    (C#MV#A, Seq[Criteria.MatchCriteria]) => C#MV, f: JValue => C#MV#A = {v: JValue => v.extract[C#MV#A]})(implicit m: Manifest[C#MV#A]) =
```

Is there a way to fix that ?

Answer (score 0):

Manifests are deprecated - use ClassTag/TypeTag instead. You actually don't need to capture ClassTag/TypeTag inside your function - you can do it inside your class (that's the only way because only class may capture its abstract type in runtime):

```
trait MV{type A; implicit val t: TypeTag[A]}

class MVString(implicit val t: TypeTag[String]) extends MV {type A = String}
```

After that - you can access TypeTag as a member `(new MVString).t` - even inside your function. The only problem is that you have to specify typeTag explicitly for every implementation. Possible solution - is to use generics in combination with abstract types:

```
abstract class MV[T](implicit val t: TypeTag[T]){type A = T}

class MVString extends MV[String]

scala> def readGenSingle4[C <: MV[T], T](a: C, b: C#A ) = a.t
readGenSingle4: [C <: MV[T], T](a: C, b: T)reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[T]

scala> readGenSingle4(new MVString, "aaaa")
res4: reflect.runtime.universe.TypeTag[String] = TypeTag[String]
```